# React after refresh TypeError: articles[(articles.length - 1)] is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a react app and I have a problem. Whenever I refresh the page I get the TypeError: articles[(articles.length - 1)] is undefined and it happens beacause of the src parameter. I want to display images of 3 newest articles that I have added to json server. But if i change src to for example "" and after that i run server everything works fine. I can change the src value back to articles[(articles.length - 1)] and without refreshing everything as it should.
I think problem is that articles are being compiled before they gets the value from json server and I don't know how can it can be fixed. Tried many ways like fetching change but none of them worked.

in ArticlesList.js

```
const ArticlesList = ({ articles }) => {
  
  return (
    <div className="whole">
      {console.log(articles.length)}
      <Carousel  fade> 
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img
            className="d-block w-100"
            src={articles[articles.length-1].img}
            alt="First slide"
            width="1100" height="400"
          />
          <Carousel.Caption>
            <h3>TESTESTESSTESTESTES</h3>
          </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img
            className="d-block w-100"
            src={articles[articles.length-2].img}
            alt="Second slide"
            width="1100" height="400"
          />
          <Carousel.Caption>
            <h3>Second slide labelxd</h3>
          </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img
            className="d-block w-100"
            src={articles[articles.length-3].img}
            alt="Third slide"
            width="1100" height="400"
          />
          <Carousel.Caption>
            <h3>Third slide label</h3>
          </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
      </Carousel>
      <CardGroup className="articles"> 
          {articles.map((article) => (
            <Col xs={4} md={4} lg={4} key={article.id}>
              <Article article={article}/>
            </Col>
          ))}
      </CardGroup>
    </div>
  )
}
```

and in App.js

```
function App() {

  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const getArticles = async () =>{
      const articlesFromServer = await fetchArticles()
      setArticles(articlesFromServer)
    }

    getArticles()
  }, [])

  const fetchArticles = async () =>{
    const res = await fetch(
      'http://localhost:5000/articles')
    const data = await res.json()

    return data
  }
  return (
    <Router>
      <>
      <Header />
      <Route path='/' exact render={(props) => (
        <>
          <ArticleList articles={articles} />
        </>
      )} />
      <Route path='/details/:id' exact component={ArticleDetails} />
      </>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that articles inside `ArticlesList` isn't undefined when you pass it in as parameter?

Comment: Are you looking at rendering the ArticleList, or ArticleDetails? Your naming convention is swapping them.

Comment: ArticleList you are right my bad

Answer (score 2):

When you're refreshing the page, application tries to get data from backend server, but your component `ArticleDetails` already loaded. Since `articles` state is an empty array, it will return `articles[articles.length-x]` as `undefined` (which in turn results in uncaught error in `articles[articles.length-x].img`).

Therefore use optional chaining as follows in such cases.

```
articles[articles.length-x]?.img
```

Complete code will be as follows.

```
const ArticlesList = ({ articles }) => {
  
  return (
    <div className="whole">
      {console.log(articles.length)}
      <Carousel  fade> 
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img
            className="d-block w-100"
            src={articles[articles.length-1]?.img}
            alt="First slide"
            width="1100" height="400"
          />
          <Carousel.Caption>
            <h3>TESTESTESSTESTESTES</h3>
          </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img
            className="d-block w-100"
            src={articles[articles.length-2]?.img}
            alt="Second slide"
            width="1100" height="400"
          />
          <Carousel.Caption>
            <h3>Second slide labelxd</h3>
          </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img
            className="d-block w-100"
            src={articles[articles.length-3]?.img}
            alt="Third slide"
            width="1100" height="400"
          />
          <Carousel.Caption>
            <h3>Third slide label</h3>
          </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
      </Carousel>
      <CardGroup className="articles"> 
          {articles.map((article) => (
            <Col xs={4} md={4} lg={4} key={article.id}>
              <Article article={article}/>
            </Col>
          ))}
      </CardGroup>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Hope this would solve your issue.

Comment: thank you very much! wow i don't know how i missed that

Answer (score 0):

#### I don't know React, but I would suggest this

This is based on my approach in Vue etc. I would check the length of `articles` before doing anything that depended on there being content in there.

In your render function, could you just insert an `if`, for example like this:

```
const ArticlesList = ({ articles }) => {
  let result = ""
  if (articles && articles.length >0){

    result += ( // Put things for .length-1 
         )
  } 
  if (articles && articles.length >1){

    result += ( // Put things for .length-2 
         )
  } 
        if (articles && articles.length >2){

    result += ( // Put things for .length-3 
         )
  }
  return result
```

Please don't shout at me if this is not correct React syntax: I am just showing you the principle I would use in Vue. 8-)

#### You could make it a loop to avoid repetition

You only need to state once how to display an article:

```
result = ""
const last3articles = articles.slice(Math.max(articles.length-3,0)).reverse()
last3articles.forEach(article=>{
   result += ........// the part for a single article.
})
```

Comment: This is also correct. But let's say if `length` is less than 2. Then `articles[articles.length-3].img` will again result in uncaught error, right ?

Comment: Ah I missed the fact that you were referencing a variety of article indices. I have updated my suggestion

Comment: It also works! thanks c:

Answer (score 0):

The main misunderstanding you have lies inside the `App` component. You assume that React componentDidMount lifecycle will wait for async calls (in your case `fetchArticles`).

What happens is that the `App` component will mount regardless if your API has returned the articles you are after. Therefore every component that doesn't guards against a not defined value for `articles` is bound to fails with null exception.

Add null checks for articles in those components.